# getting exception "desired type = NSOrderedSet; given type = __NSArrayM " in swift while mapping collection

Tags: ios, swift, mapping

[1 I have ticked sorted]I am using swift verison `pod 'FastEasyMapping', '~> 1.2'`

I am getting the below error:

> desired type = NSOrderedSet; given type = __NSArrayM

while mapping using method

```
FEMDeserializer.collection(fromRepresentation:mapping:context)
```

Getting exception in line ::

```
mapping.addToManyRelationshipMapping(ABC.defaultmapping(), forProperty: "cde", keyPath: "CDE")
```

property of `cde` is in  ABC is

```
@NSManaged var cde : NSOrderedSet!
```

Comment: Any Solaution ??

Comment: `cde` is an array, not an ordered set.  Your relationship doesn't have the "Ordered" checkbox ticked in your core data model.

Comment: I checked it is ticked in

Comment: Any one have any Solution ?@Paulw11 I Checked in my database its ticked as a ordered .I have also attached screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the Reason it was silly mistake  that I wrote wrong key I write this ::

mapping.addToManyRelationshipMapping(ABC.defaultmapping(), forProperty: "CDE", keyPath: "cde")

that should be actually :: 
 mapping.addToManyRelationshipMapping(ABC.defaultmapping(), forProperty: "cde", keyPath: "CDE")

Thanks All